# Chrome using Windows 8 mode

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am looking into a way to use the same method Chrome is using to switch between Desktop and Windows 8 modes.

I cannot help but wonder how Google was able to pull such a thing. In Windows store, Chrome is registered as a desktop app which, as I understand it, should not be allowed to run in Windows 8 mode since MS made it clear that any Windows 8, formerly Metro, application needs to be downloaded through the store and not from an external link, and these applications need to be verified and signed by MS.

I am currently browsing Chrome's code trying to figure out how they did it and I was hoping if someone has read a document or article about developing such a thing.

Regards.

P.S. As I am unsure where should I post such a question and since I now see that people are voting to close this question, I think it would be nice if one of the voters can take some time and comment... BTW IMHO, this is a valid programming question.

Comment: There are special exemptions for browsers.

Comment: @Luke can you refer me to the article that describes this exemption?

Comment: your question is much welcomed. I had the same question in my mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took some searching, but [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=243079) (DOCX, download) is the Microsoft white-paper describing the special exemption/privileges for whatever app is registered as the default handler for the `http` protocol.